# Dell Inspiron/Windows Vista sleep/hibernate issue

Tags: windows, windows-vista, sleep, hibernate, dell-inspiron

When I hit the sleep button in Windows the computer looks like it's going into Sleep mode but a few seconds later it's restarted, and stops with this error message:

> internal hard disk drive not found
>   To resolve this issue, try to reseat the drive.
>
> No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
>   Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics.

The computer is running Windows Vista (SP2) and I have installed all available Windows Updates and the latest manufacturer drivers.

I have already tried to reseated the drive, ran the onboard diagnostics and there were no errors.

I have changed the power settings for all devices where it's available so that they are not allowed to wake up the computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution. The problem was caused by the Broadcom Wireless Network Adapter in my Dell Inspiron 1525.

Here's what I did:

1. Start
2. Control Panel
3. Device Manager
4. Expand "Network adapters"
5. Double-click "Broadcom 802.11g Network Adapter"
6. Click "Advanced"
7. Select "Wake-Up Mode" from the list
8. Change the value to "None"